Automatically delete podcasts after playing in Rhythm box
I'm not sure if this is a simple question to answer and I'm not seeing the solution but is there a way to automatically delete podcasts I've already listened too? Maybe the solution is a plugin that exists? I've searched through the preferences and didn't have anything stick out to me as the solution. I like the function of automatically downloading new podcasts that come out, but I could see how this could get out of hand if they're not 'cleaned up' automatically as well. Thanks for all your help on what I'm sure is a simply answer!
